# selection sort char and int

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, selection

I have an array of char and int: {6,A,n,D,5,1,j,e,F}.
I need to sort this by selection to achieve this result: {e,j,n,6,1,5,A,D,F}.

At the beginning, I would like to check if a selection sort works properly, but 
there is some problem.
I converted char to int ( there is another solution to display integers and chars together in one array? ) so I have an array of integers: 6,65,110,68,5,1,106,101,70.
But my sort gives me this effect: 5,6,65,68,68,68,68,110.

```
    void selection_sort(int tab1[], int size) {
        int index;
        for(int i = 0; i < size-1; i++)
        {
            index = i;
            for(int j = i + 1; j < size; j++)
            {
                if(tab1[j] < tab1[index])
                {
                    index = j;
                    swap(tab1[j], tab1[i]);

                }

            }
            cout << " " << tab1[index];
        } 
}

    int main() {
        const int size = 9;
        int tab[size] = {6, 'A', 'n', 'D', 5, 1, 'j', 'e', 'F'};
        cout << "Before sort: " << endl << endl;

        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            cout << " " << tab[i];
        }
        cout << endl << endl;

        cout << "After sort: " << endl << endl;
        selection_sort(tab,size);


        return 0;
     }
```

Comment: `I have an array of char and int:` Nope.

Comment: char is like an intereger (less bytes)... every symbol is in momory a number... check this out: http://www.chip.de/ii/1/2/5/4/9/5/8/0/ascii-93c823e7009f26b0.png this is the number to symbol table (ascii)... you can calculate with chars like with integers also you can make < > operations

Comment: just for fun I did what your statement actually said: An array of char and int (I made (an unsafe) union). And sort it with lower letters first, then numbers, then upper letters. You can see it here: http://ideone.com/J30zY8

Comment: @bolov Thank you but your uses special function in c++ and object oriented programming.  I need to write this with basic knowledge to undestand how it works properly. But thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
if(tab1[j] < tab1[index])
    {
     index = j;
     swap(tab1[j], tab1[i]);
    }
```

Try:

```
for(int j = i + 1; j < size; j++)
   {
    if(tab1[j] < tab1[index])
        {
         index = j;      
        }
   }
swap(tab1[index], tab1[i]);
```

You've to swap the smallest element found in the second loop, but you're swapping for every iteration in the second loop. That's why you're getting the wrong values.

**Update:**

There's another mistake:

```
cout << " " << tab1[index];
```

It should be:

```
 cout << " " << tab1[i];
```

You can try the code with my suggested changes here: http://code.geeksforgeeks.org/tjiwnu

It works.

Comment: It doesn't work properly also. It shows: 6,65,110,68,68,110,106,106.
But my code works for sort of strings. But for numbers not. Do you have some idea?

Comment: @gryzek post your swap function

Comment: @gryzek here's the code: http://code.geeksforgeeks.org/tjiwnu  . It works. There was another mistake:  cout << " " << tab1[index]; It should be:  cout << " " << tab1[i];